# How to reproduce the RTP bleed vulnerability?

Tags: proxy, voip, sip

I need to demonstrate RTP bleed on an older version of Asterisk/RTPProxy, but I'm struggling with setting up the environment. Can somebody please tell me how to configure a proxy and two clients properly to be able to send .wav files through a call, and use [rtpnatscan](https://github.com/kapejod/rtpnatscan) to redirect RTP packets to a remote machine?